# Get First day of last month timestamp with Carbon

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to get the timestamp in milliseconds  for first day of last month and last day of last month using Carbon in laravel.

I have tried to do it with carbon::parse, which is achieved. But I want to instantiate the Carbon class simply to achieve the same.

This is the code that works fine with Carbon::parse

`Carbon::parse('first day of last month',$timezone)->timestamp`

But I want to achieve the same using something like below.

`$start = new Carbon('first day of last month');`

`$end = new Carbon('last day of last month');`

The output should be timestamp in milliseconds. Like `1555704794000`

Answer (score 3):

You may try the below code

```
$previous_month_start = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->format('x');
$previous_month_end = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->format('x');
```